# Necesito ayuda con un elseif

Tags: php, html, mysql, modal

Necesito ayuda para este `else if` que no me lo registra bien, quiero  registrar una imagen en un modal pero el que lo valida me da error no sée si se necesita algo especial para que lo valide correctamente porque me da error como si no hubiera puesto nada.

```
          var_dump($_FILES['imagen']);
    if (empty($_POST['incidencia'])){
        $errors[] = "Por favor seleccione una incidencia";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['tema'])){
        $errors[] = "Tema vacío";
    }  elseif (empty($_POST['detalle'])) {
        $errors[] = "detalle vacío";
    } elseif (empty($_FILES['imagen']['name'])) {
        $errors[] = "imagen vacía";
    }  elseif (
        !empty($_POST['incidencia'])
        && !empty($_POST['tema'])
        && !empty($_POST['detalle'])
        && !empty($_FILES['imagen'])
    )
```

El html

```
                <?php
    if (isset($con))
    {
?>

<?php
    if (isset($con))
    {
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal20" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Agregar nueva incidencia</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="guardar_ticket" name="guardar_ticket" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="incidencia" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Incidencia</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Incidencia" name="incidencia" placeholder="incidencia" required>
            </div>
          </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tema" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Asunto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tema" name="tema" placeholder="Asunto" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="detalle" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Detalle</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="detalle" name="detalle" placeholder="Detalle" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imagen" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Imagen</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input id="imagen" type="file" name="imagen" > 
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_datos">Guardar datos</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

adjunto despues de hacer el var_dump
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto tambien la imagen de la DB
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el js

```
                  $(document).ready(function(){
        load(1);
    });

    function load(page){
        var q= $("#q").val();
        $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url:'./ajax/buscar_ticket.php?action=ajax&page='+page+'&q='+q,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
             $('#loader').html('<img src="./img/ajax-loader.gif"> Cargando...');
          },
            success:function(data){
                $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $('#loader').html('');

            }
        })
    }



        function eliminar (Nticket)
    {
        var q= $("#q").val();
    if (confirm("Realmente deseas eliminar el la entrega")){    
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./ajax/buscar_ticket.php",
    data: "Nticket="+Nticket,"q":q,
     beforeSend: function(objeto){
        $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
      },
    success: function(datos){
    $("#resultados").html(datos);
    load(1);
    }
        });
    }
    }
```

el otro

```
              $( "#guardar_ticket" ).submit(function( event ) {
            $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

            var parametros = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/nuevo_ticket.php",
        data: parametros,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
        $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
        load(1);
              }
        });
           event.preventDefault();
          })
          $( "#editar_ticket" ).submit(function( event ) {
           $('#actualizar_datos2').attr("disabled", true);

        var parametros = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/editar_ticket.php",
        data: parametros,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados_ajax2").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados_ajax2").html(datos);
        $('#actualizar_datos2').attr("disabled", false);
        load(1);
      }
        });
       event.preventDefault();
      })


        function get_user_ID(Nticket){
        $("#user_Nticket_mod").val(Nticket);
    }

        function obtener_datos(Nticket){
        var incidencia = $("#incidencia"+Nticket).val(Nticket);
        var tema = $("#tema"+Nticket).val(Nticket);
        var detalle = $("#detalle"+Nticket).val(Nticket);
        var imageni = $("imageni"+Nticket).val(Nticket);

        $("#mod_Nticket").val(Nticket);
        $("#incidencia").val(incidencia);
        $("#tema").val(tema);
        $("#detalle").val(detalle);
        $("#imageni").val(imageni);
    }
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error ?

Comment: ok ya  subo el error

Comment: **Te falta un paréntesis al final de todos los `if`**. Ese código me da dolor de cabeza, yo almacenaría los valores de cada `POST` en una variable, luego evaluaría las variables en un bloque `switch`.

Comment: en donde al final??

Comment: Al final de los if, aquí: `&& !empty($_POST['imageni'])` falta un paréntesis. Además, no haces nada con la última condición.

Comment: aa no hay esta lo que pasa es que esta mas abajo mi error por no ponerlo

Comment: puedes colocar el formulario HTML cuando sube imagenes hay que agregarle una linea mas

Comment: Pero cuando esto se cumple: `}  elseif (
        !empty($_POST['incidencia'])
        && !empty($_POST['tema'])
        && !empty($_POST['detalle'])
        && !empty($_POST['imageni'])
     ) `  no asignas nada, no haces nada dentro de esa condición.

Comment: si pero el error me lo da hay en el elseif de la imageni lo demas ps es el insert select verifica si ya esta pero hay no tengo error

Comment: agrega esta linea en el form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios errores:

1. El `name` de tu `input` dice imagen y tu estas capturando `$_POST['imageni']`
2. una imagen se captura usando `$_FILES['']`
3. Tu etiqueta `form` debe tener enctype='multipart/form-data'
4. Prueba haciendo la condición así:

   ```
   elseif (empty($_FILES['imagen']['name'])) {

   }
   ```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

En tu js debes hacer lo siguiente, como estas enviando una imagen es necesario utilizar un FormData(); de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#guardar_ticket").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var Incidencia = $("#Incidencia").val();
    var tema = $("#tema").val();
    var detalle = $("#detalle").val();

    var imagen = $("#imagen")[0].files[0];

    var parametros =  new FormData();
    parametros.append('Incidencia', Incidencia);
    parametros.append('tema', tema);
    parametros.append('detalle', detalle);
    parametros.append('imagen', imagen);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/nuevo_ticket.php",
        data: parametros,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
        },
        success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
            $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
            load(1);
        }
    });

    /* Acá sigues con la lógica que tengas en esta función */
})

/* Sigues con la lógica de tu programa */
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66359/discussion-on-answer-by-camilo-vasquez-necesito-ayuda-con-un-elseif).

Answer (score 3):

Te exhorto a que en vez de anidar los if de esa manera hagas lo siguiente

```
//Inicializo el arreglo de los errores (vacío)
$errors = array();
//Voy capturando los errores de 1 en 1
if (empty($_POST['incidencia'])){
        $errors[] = "Por favor seleccione una incidencia";
    } 
if (empty($_POST['tema'])){
        $errors[] = "Tema vacío";
    }  
if (empty($_POST['detalle'])) {
        $errors[] = "detalle vacío";
    } 
if (empty($_POST['imageni'])) {
        $errors[] = "imagen vacía";
}
//Si no hay ningún error
if(count($errors) == 0){
   //Código a ejecutar cuando no hay errores
}
```

El problema de anidarlos como los tenías era que si la primera condición se cumplía no entraba a ningún otro if, por eso si tenias más de un campo vacío el solo veía el primero que tuvieras condicionado en el listado de If