# Undefined al ingresar el valor en la DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

Me conecta perfecto todos los valores pero al ingresar una parte que se llama incidencia me aparece escriba lo que escriba me aparece undefined

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo donde se ingresan los datos a la DB

```
                require_once ("../config/db.php");
        require_once ("../config/conexion.php");


            $incidencia = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["incidencia"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $tema = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["tema"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $detalle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["detalle"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $imagen = ($_FILES['imagen']);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE incidencia = '" . $incidencia . "' OR tema = '" . $tema . "';";
            $query_check_incidencia = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (incidencia, tema, detalle, imagen)
                        VALUES('".$incidencia."','".$tema."','" . $detalle . "', '" . $_FILES['imagen']['name'] . "');";
                $query_new_incidencia_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);



     else {
        $errors[] = "Un error desconocido ocurrió.";
    }

    if (isset($errors)){

        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Error!</strong> 
                <?php
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            echo $error;
                        }
                    ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        if (isset($messages)){

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                echo $message;
                            }
                        ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

         ?>
```

y este es donde yo ingreso los datos

```
                <?php
    if (isset($con))
    {
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal20" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Agregar nueva incidencia</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="guardar_ticket" name="guardar_ticket" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="incidencia" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Incidencia</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incidencia" name="incidencia" placeholder="incidencia" required>
            </div>
          </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tema" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Asunto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tema" name="tema" placeholder="Asunto" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="detalle" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Detalle</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="detalle" name="detalle" placeholder="Detalle" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imagen" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Imagen</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input id="imagen" type="file" name="imagen" > 
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_datos">Guardar datos</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

inserto el js

```
                $( "#guardar_ticket" ).submit(function( event ) {
           $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

           var incidencia = $("incidencia").val();
           var tema = $("#tema").val();
           var detalle = $("#detalle").val();

          var imagen = $("#imagen")[0].files[0];

            var parametros =  new FormData();

       parametros.append('incidencia', incidencia);            
       parametros.append('tema', tema); 
       parametros.append('detalle', detalle); 
       parametros.append('imagen', imagen);

       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/nuevo_ticket.php",
        data: parametros,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
        $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
        load(1);
          }
          });
         event.preventDefault();
         })
          $( "#editar_ticket" ).submit(function( event ) {
       $('#actualizar_datos2').attr("disabled", true);

           var parametros = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/editar_ticket.php",
        data: parametros,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados_ajax2").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados_ajax2").html(datos);
        $('#actualizar_datos2').attr("disabled", false);
        load(1);
          }
      });
          event.preventDefault();
        })


        function get_user_Nticket(Nticket){
            $("#user_Nticket_mod").val(Nticket);
        }

function obtener_datos(Nticket){
        var incidencia = $("#incidencia"+Nticket).val(Nticket);
        var tema = $("#tema"+Nticket).val(Nticket);
        var detalle = $("#detalle"+Nticket).val(Nticket);
        var imagen = $("imagen"+Nticket).val(Nticket);

        $("#mod_Nticket").val(Nticket);
        $("#incidencia").val(incidencia);
        $("#tema").val(tema);
        $("#detalle").val(detalle);
        $("#imagen").val(imagen);
    }
```

Comment: Supongo que estás enviando los datos al servidor mediante Ajax, muestra el código donde envías los datos y la forma en que los insertas en la base de datos.

Comment: listo ya actualice la respuesta

Comment: Kevin, muestra el js, cuando haces operaciones por ajax es importante ver como envías y como recibes la información. El undefined puede ser por que desde javascript se esta accediendo al elemento de forma erronea

Comment: Verifica el resultado de esto: `$incidencia = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["incidencia"],ENT_QUOTES)));` haciendo: **`echo $incidencia;`** Si usaras consultas preparadas te evitarías el dichoso escape_string, el cual en realidad no te ayuda a escapar de nada. Aún usándolo te pueden inyectar código malicioso. La mejor solución para blindar el código son las consultas preparadas. El `undefined` suena a Javascript, pero no veo tu código Javascript donde capturas ese valor.

Comment: pero camilo Vasquez si tu me ayudaste a modificar el js

Comment: Si, pero tu antes tenías el id incidencia con "I" mayúscula y ahora lo veo con "i" minúscula, si no lo cambias en el selector de jQuery no te capturará el valor

Comment: si ya se y ya lo corregi lo puse en minuscula todo las "incidencia" estan en minuscula excepto las del tipo titulos y eso

Comment: Si te refieres a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105775/29967)  en el código de envío vía Ajax no se ve que en ningún momento envíes el valor de incidencia, al menos yo no lo veo. Y haces movimientos extraños con la variable, por ejemplo: `$("#incidencia").val(incidencia);`

Comment: Y lo cambiaste en la línea `datos.append('Incidencia', Incidencia);`

Comment: ehh no era parametros.append

Comment: Si en parámetros, es lo mismo es solo el nombre de una variable la cual puedes llamar como quieras, el hecho es que el 'Incidencia' que esta entre comillas debe llevar i minúscula por que así lo recibes en tu php `parametros.append('incidencia', Incidencia);` .Recuerda que no se debe hablar mucho en los comentarios, revisa esa parte de tu código o actualiza tu pregunta

Comment: si desde la primera vez de que me ayudaste la cambien parametros.append('incidencia', incidencia);

Comment: Actualiza con el código js !

Comment: ya esta en la prgunta a lo ultimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está en esta línea

```
var incidencia = $("incidencia").val();
```

Como estás capturando un elemento por su `id` debes colocar el `#` así

```
var incidencia = $("#incidencia").val();
```

Comment: bua camilo te daba un hijo pero soy hombre XD gracias crack

Comment: Calmado tigre jaja todo bien

Comment: ok hasta otra crack